# An error caused a batch to fail without attempting to load data for batch 000--9999 while Synchronizing with SymmetricDS Server

Tags: android, symmetricds, sourceforge

I have followed this [Link](https://medium.com/data-weekly/data-synchronization-with-android-d050df98db6a)

ERROR:

"An error caused a batch to fail without attempting to load data for batch 000--9999"

Android is getting connected to SymmetricDS server but unable to pull data and through this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iORea.png)

My dbProvider class is:

```
public class DbProvider extends ContentProvider {

//TODO: Update REGISTRATION_URL with Sync URL of corp-000
private final String REGISTRATION_URL = "http://172.18.21.239:8080/sync/corp-000";
private final String NODE_ID = "002";
private final String NODE_GROUP = "store";

final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item(\n" +
        "    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
        "    name VARCHAR\n" +
        ");";

final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEM_SELLING_PRICE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_selling_price(\n" +
        "    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    store_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    price DECIMAL NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    cost DECIMAL,\n" +
        "    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, store_id)\n" +
        ");";

final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SALE_TRANSACTION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sale_transaction(\n" +
        "    tran_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
        "    store_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    workstation VARCHAR NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    day VARCHAR NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    seq INTEGER NOT NULL\n" +
        ");\n";

final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SALE_RETURN_LINE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sale_return_line_item(\n" +
        "    tran_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
        "    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    price DECIMAL NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    returned_quantity INTEGER\n" +
        ");\n";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";

// Handle to a new DatabaseHelper.
private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

/**
 * This class helps open, create, and upgrade the database file. Set to package visibility
 * for testing purposes.
 */
static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        // calls the super constructor, requesting the default cursor factory.
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes the provider by creating a new DatabaseHelper. onCreate() is called
 * automatically when Android creates the provider in response to a resolver request from a
 * client.
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    // Creates a new helper object. Note that the database itself isn't opened until
    // something tries to access it, and it's only created if it doesn't already exist.
    mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

    // Init the DB here
    mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEM);
    mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEM_SELLING_PRICE);
    mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SALE_TRANSACTION);
    mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SALE_RETURN_LINE_ITEM);

    // Register the database helper, so it can be shared with the SymmetricService
    SQLiteOpenHelperRegistry.register(DATABASE_NAME, mOpenHelper);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SymmetricService.class);

    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_SQLITEOPENHELPER_REGISTRY_KEY, DATABASE_NAME);
    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_REGISTRATION_URL, REGISTRATION_URL);
    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_EXTERNAL_ID, NODE_ID);
    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_NODE_GROUP_ID, NODE_GROUP);
    intent.putExtra("sourceGroupId", "corp");
    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_START_IN_BACKGROUND, true);


    // TODO: Update properties with the desired Symmetric parameters (e.g. File Sync parameters)
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ParameterConstants.FILE_SYNC_ENABLE, "true");
    properties.put("start.file.sync.tracker.job", "true");
    properties.put("start.file.sync.push.job", "true");
    properties.put("start.file.sync.pull.job", "true");
    properties.put("job.file.sync.pull.period.time.ms", "10000");
    properties.put("initial.load.use.extract.job.enabled", "true");
    properties.put("stream.to.file.enabled", "true");

    intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_PROPERTIES, properties);

    getContext().startService(intent);

    // Assumes that any failures will be reported by a thrown exception.
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}

public String getType(Uri uri) {

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

help me out to resolve this issue.

Same issue has also been posted [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/1354726/thread/1925d716/)!

but all provided solutions are unable to resolve my issue.

DbProvider is being used in mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into sale_transaction (store_id, workstation, day, seq) values ('301','3','1',55)";

private static final String SELECT_SQL = "select * from item";

private final int COLUMN_WIDTH = 14;

/**
 * onCreate is called when Android starts this Activity from scratch.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText sqlTextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sqlTextField);
    final TextView outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    outputTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    Button runButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.runButton);
    runButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String sql = sqlTextField.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteOpenHelperRegistry.lookup(DbProvider.DATABASE_NAME).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ex.toString(), duration);
            toast.show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String tableFormat = "";
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
            if (buff.length() == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    tableFormat += "%-" + COLUMN_WIDTH + "s|";
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
                    columnNames[j] = StringUtils.abbreviate(columnNames[j], COLUMN_WIDTH);
                }

                buff.append(String.format(tableFormat, columnNames)).append("\n");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                values.add(StringUtils.abbreviate(cursor.getString(i), COLUMN_WIDTH));
            }
            buff.append(String.format(tableFormat, values.toArray(new String[0]))).append("\n");
        }

        outputTextView.setText(buff.toString());

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Executed " + sql;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    });

    Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        sqlTextField.setText("");
        outputTextView.setText("");
    });

    Button selectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton.setOnClickListener(v -> sqlTextField.setText(SELECT_SQL));

    Button insertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insertButton);
    insertButton.setOnClickListener(v -> sqlTextField.setText(INSERT_SQL));

    Button newFileButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newFileButton);
    newFileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String fileName = sqlTextField.getText().toString();
        File newFile = new File(getStorageDir(v.getContext(), "SymDS").getAbsoluteFile() + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public File getStorageDir(Context context, String directoryName) {
    File file =
            new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/"), directoryName);

    System.out.println("canRead " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canRead());
    System.out.println("canWrite " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite());

    boolean ok = file.mkdirs(); //create folders where write files
    if (!ok) {
        CharSequence text = "Failed to create dir " + file;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    return file;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: How is the `DbProvider` registered to let the symmetricDs know that it has to load it and use it?

Comment: It is loaded and used in mainActivity class